# Transfer files from SFTP server using PowerShell Only if files doesn't exist

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0, sftp, winscp

Needing guidance to transfer files from an SFTP server to a network shared folder but only if the file name does not exist.

I am able to do that now, but have been struggling with the same name files being over written on the folder transferring to and would prefer to skip same name file.

Trying to get the powershell script to check if file exist, if so skip and do not transfer. Below is what I currently have and tried and does not seem to work, it over writes my existing files with the same name and that is not what I am seeking. I will continue doing further research as well.

```
# Load the Assemblemy and setup the session properties
try
{
   # Load WinSCP . NET assembly
   Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"

   # setup session options
   $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
      Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
      HostName = "0.0.0.0"
      UserName = "usernam01"
      Password = "Password"
      SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-ed25519 256 **************************************"
  }


$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
#end

try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        # Download files
        $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
        $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary
        #$transferOptions.FileMask = "*>=1D"

        $transferResult =
            $session.GetFiles("/home/*.csv", "\\fww\folder\", $False, $transferOptions)
        $remotePath = "\\fww\folder\"
        if ($session.FileExists($remotePath))
        {
             Write-Host "File $remotePath exists"
        }

        # Throw on any error
        $transferResult.Check()

        # Print results
        foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
        {
            Write-Host "Transfer of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded"
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
```

Comment: Are you just trying to mirror the remote files to a local path (as in, a one way sync to make sure the local copies match the remote ones)?

Comment: Yes, and no. I said yes because I want to get all files from my SFTP server into a network folder but in the network folder we will archive files every so often so it will not mirror properly. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Just seeking to transfer .csv files from SFTP server to network folder if the files doen't already exist in my network folder, if it doesn't exist download(transfer) the file over.

Answer (score 0):

## Local Synchronization

I think a local synchonization will probably work for you, I'm assuming you're worried about files being archived/moved on the remote end causing the local copy to lose those files. If you set `bool removeFiles` of the [`Session.SynchronizeDirectories`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_synchronizedirectories) method call to `$False`, it should not remove obsolete files that don't exist in the remote source.

### If a local sync won't work for you

If a local synchronization isn't acceptable in your case, you can make use of [`Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory) to list all files you are interested in, and transfer them one at a time if the local file does not exist.

You may also do well to go over [this page of the WinSCP .NET documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_modified_files) about additional techniques for transferring only newer/modified files.

Comment: Thank you, I have gone through this page previously but was seeking to see if there was a way to skip if files exist type of scenario. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes there is, local synchronization. But you said synchronization doesn't work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on WinSCP article [Checking file existence and timestamp](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_check_existence_timestamp) (note the example in code comments), you can use synchronization with [`Session.SynchronizeDirectories`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_synchronizedirectories) like:

```bsh
transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
$transferOptions.FileMask = ".csv"
$session.SynchronizeDirectories(
    [WinSCP.SynchronizationMode]::Local, "\\fww\folder", /home", $False, $False,
    [WinSCP.SynchronizationCriteria]::Time, $transferOptions).Check()
```

Depending on your needs, you can replace `[WinSCP.SynchronizationMode]::Local` with `[WinSCP.SynchronizationMode]::Local`, if you never want to download existing files even if the remote file has newer timestamp.

---

Or you can simply list the files in the folder with [`Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory) or [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles) and process them any way you like. To [check for existence of the local files](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence), use [`Test-Path` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path).